# Python all() and bool() empty cases?

Tags: python, built-in

when using help(all), it returns:

```
all(iterable)=>bool
return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.    
if the iterable is empty, return True
```

help(bool) returns:

```
bool(x) -> bool
 |  
 |  Returns True when the argument x is true, False otherwise.
 |  The builtins True and False are the only two instances of the class bool.
 |  The class bool is a subclass of the class int, and cannot be subclassed.
```

when trying:

```
>>>bool()
False

>>>all([])
True
```

my question is, in case that all's input is the empty list/dict/tuple(i.e. iterator), what's passed to bool??
and how come it returns True, as it's dependent on bool?

Comment: Universal quantification over the empty set is *true*. That's not a Python thing, that's just a fact.

Comment: Think of `all` as "no-`False`". An empty iterable contains no `False`-y values, so `all` returns `True`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`bool()` is never invoked if `all()`'s argument is empty.  That's why the docs point out the behavior of `all()` on an empty input as a special case.

The behavior `bool() == False` is irrelevant to what `all()` does in any case.  By the way, in Python `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so `bool() == False` is necessary to be compatible with that `int() == 0`.

As to why, e.g., `all([])` is `True`, it's to preserve useful identities.  Most importantly, for any non-empty sequence `x` it's desirable that

```
all(x) == (bool(x[0]) and all(x[1:]))
```

and `all([]) == True` is the only result allowing that identity to hold for all values of `x`.

Answer (score 7):

```
all(iterable)
```

...is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to be equivalent to;

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

...which returns *False if and only if any value in the list converts to False*.

Since there is no element in the list you pass in, no element converts to False, and the result of the function call is True.

Answer (score 6):

> […] what's passed to bool?

Nothing – and not the “nothing” of `bool()`. `bool` is never called. Is every element in an empty sequence truthy? Yes! There aren’t any that aren’t, after all.

Comment: While I agree with the logic, you could equally argue that all elements are false - the important thing is that it's documented behavior

Comment: @PeterGibson: You could say that all elements are false, and you would be right, but that doesn’t have any bearing on `all`, since it doesn’t check whether all elements are false and shouldn’t in the case of a non-empty list either. (That is to say, not all elements are false in `[True, False]`, but `all` will still obviously return `False`.)

Comment: @PeterGibson: You could argue that, and you could even implement it that way in your own language, but it turns out that that convention is much less useful.  Making `all([]) == True` results in the invariant that for any list `l` and element `x`, `all(l + [x])` is `True` if and only if `all(l)` and `bool(x)` are `True`, even in the case of the empty list `l`.  Setting `all([]) == False` breaks that invariant.

Comment: On further consideration, I realise you're both right. The point I (meant) to make is that sometimes the documented behavior may not agree with what seems logical, however it is correct *because* it is documented behavior.

Comment: @PeterGibson Sort of the other way around. It's documented that way *because* it's logical. As in, it's how mathematicians would do it. Yes, they're all true, and they're all false. But "all" only asks, "Are all of them true?" A hypothetical `allnot` ("Are all of them false?") would also return true in the empty case. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it's implemented something like:

```
def all(inp):
    return not any(not bool(x) for x in inp)
```

so an empty iterator is "vacuously true." This makes sense, and corresponds with similar notions in logic -- we usually say that a universal quantifier holds of some proposition over a domain even if an existential one doesn't.